# Summation in recurrence: $T(n) = cn + \frac{4}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}T(k)$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I search the entire forum and couldn't find a solution to this.
Can you please help me solve this recurrence equation?
$$
T(n) = cn + \frac{4}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T(k)
$$

Comment: Do you want a closed form for $T(n)$ ? If yes, I guess, it's highly unlikely for $T(n)$ defined above to have one. Moreover, the recurrence is not well-defined, there is no base case.

Comment: What have you tried so far? People on here are more likely to help if you showed that you put some effort into working the problem yourself.

Comment: The base case is constant. I tried to express T(n+1) with T(n) by canceling the sum but it didn't work out. In general i tried alot of algabra. But no luck for me.

Answer (score 0):

Write your recurrence as:
$$
n^2 T(n) = c n^3 + 4 \sum_{0 \le k \le n - 1} T(n)
$$
If you substract this from the next step you get:
$$
(n + 1)^2 T(n + 1) - (n^2 + 4) T(n) = c (n + 1)^3 - c n^3
$$
This is a linear recurrence of order 1, so solvable. Write it as:
$$
T(n + 1) - u_n T(n) = f_n
$$
dividing by $s_n = \prod_{0 \le k \le n} u_k$ gives the difference between $T(n + 1)/s_n$ and $T(n) /s_{n - 1}$, and all you need is to sum up $f_n / s_n$. The result is probably a hairy summation, unlikely to have a simple form. In any case, it should have hypergeometric terms, perhaps Gosper-Zeilberger (see e.g. [A = B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html) by Petkovsek, Wilf and Zeilberger, or look for Gosper or Zeilberger in your tame CAS) is able to simplify it (or show it is hopeless).

Comment: do you have a mistake in line 4? $$ -(n^2 + 4) $$

Comment: Right. Thanks!${}$

Comment: What do you mean in line 8 :"you need is to sum up fn/sn" ?

Comment: @user3126715, sum over $0 \le k \le n - 1$ on both sides, the LHS telescopes nicely.

Comment: $$\frac{T(n+1)}{S_{n}} -\frac{T(n)}{S_{n-1}} = \frac{f_{n}}{S_{n}}$$ Sum on all this? how? What should i do now?

Comment: anyone please??